Copying slides from one Keynote presentation to another in iCloud
Can slides be moved from one presentation to another in Keynote in iCloud? I cannot simply download them both and do this via copy and paste locally because one presentation was created a couple of years ago and the other more recently so to download both on my machine I would need to update Keynote which requires an update of my OS X which I do not want to do at the moment.
